# What happens when you pick a Power-up after you die?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I was wondering, what happens when you die, and while falling, you pick up a Power-up on your way down?

Comment: You collect coins and spin tokens, but I think vehicle pickups are no ops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You *can* collect **coins** after you die. The game tracks how many coins you collected.
- You *can* collect **spin tokens** after you die. The game tracks how many times this happens.
- You *cannot* collect **vehicle powerups** after you die. I've just managed to pass squarely above one using a post-mortem nuke; nothing happened. Unfortunately it happened too quickly for me to grab a screenshot.

You can see these numbers under the Death portion of your Statistics in the Stash.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to pick up vehicles after your demise. I have seen this personally on at least one run, where Mr. Steakfries' body passed right through a power up without anything happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually collect S.A.M. after you die.

I just now flew toward the flying 'M' as a missile was coming onto the screen. Unfortunately, the missile got me just before I was able to get the M. The animation in which you see Barry pulled forward and placed into S.A.M. still occurred, but there was a yellow outline  (the burning outline when you're killed by a missile) around him. Then he was placed in S.A.M. and the outline was gone. S.A.M. moved forward at his normal speed, but I was unable to lift its arm.

After about five or ten seconds I was taken to the slot machine screen (game over) without being S.A.M. being destroyed. The polaroid on the menu screen is a picture of Barry inside of S.A.M., but it is hard to see because there is a slightly transparent yellow overlay covering the entire picture.

So, even though I picked the M up after dying, the game still registered that I was dead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah using revives when a power-up is on the screen will make the power-up disappear too so don't think of collecting it by using revives

Answer (score -1):

You pass right through it, although I have had a bug where I wasn't in the vehicle, and I got it before dying.